# Is it possible to use PHP inside Xcode for iOS app development?

Tags: php, ios, xcode

Is this possible? I have tried using Google and nothing shows up, so figured I would come to the great Stack Overflow to get the answer for sure.

If this isn't possible, I'm looking for a way for uitextfields to be automatically sent to a specific email address on click of a button.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What makes you think Apple would ever include a PHP interpreter inside iOS?

Comment: You could also research before posting stuff. You know, [like this](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=programming+basics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=7je8U-yOLqPE8geXkYGICQ#channel=fs&q=how+coding+works)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. Apple products use objective-c or the newer products use the swift language.